# having problems with some variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

   interface triangleInfo {
              base: number;
              height: number;
              area: number;
              error: string;
            }

            export default class triangleArea extends React.Component<triangleInfo> {
              constructor(props: triangleInfo) {
                super(props);

                //initializing variables to undefined

                this.state = {
                  base: 0,
                  height: 0,
                  area: undefined,
                  error: ""
                };
              }

              //Handling change of input Base and HEIGHT

              handleChange = (input: "base" | "height", value) => {
                this.setState({
                  [input]: value
                });
              };

              //getArea function to calculate Area
              getArea = triangleInfo => {
                triangleInfo.preventDefault();
                const { base, height } = this.props;

                if (base > 0 && height > 0) {
                  this.setState({
                    area: (base * height) / 2
                  });
                } else {
                  this.setState({
                    base: undefined,
                    height: undefined,
                    area: undefined,
                    error: "Please enter the values correctly."
                  });
                }
              };

              render() {
                return (
                  //...
                  <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.getArea}>
                      <p>Calculate the base of a triangle!</p>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="base"
                        placeholder="base"
                        value={base}
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange("base", e.target.value)}
                      />
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="height"
                        placeholder="height"
                        value={height}
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange("height", e.target.value)}
                      />
                      <button type="submit">Get Area</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  //...
                );
              }
            }
```

I am working on a small project to practice my skills and to improve my understanding of reactjs and typescript but I am encountering and error and I am stuck.

i have tried a lot of stuff. However, i am not very experienced on it.
Also, the main error is in the inputs value
actual be able to do the calculation.}

Error I get is Cannot find name 'base'.ts(2304) line 68

Comment: So what is the error you are getting? Can you post it in your original code?

Comment: yes, I already added it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not declare `base` and `height` inside the `render()` method.  You need to repeat that line `const { base, height } = this.props;` at the beginning of `render()`.

Comment: that worked! thank you I was initializing it just inside the getArea functio, however now when I want to use this component on my main app it won't work. import React from 'react';
import triangleArea from "./components/triangleArea";
import './App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to someMath!</h1>
      <triangleArea/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the value of your state.... Change the value of your input to reflect what is in state.

```
value={this.state.base}
```

And the onChange..

```
onChange={this.onChange}
```

Bind this to your functions in your constructor..

```
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
```

Your on change, I am unsure what happens there but this example should work for you. This gets the value of your target whenever its value changes and sets that value to state.

```
onChange = (e) => {        
   this.setState({
     [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
 };
```

Since you are using a button to submit.

```
onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}


onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var data = {            
            base: this.state.base   
        }
}
```

Also for this to work you will have to give your inputs a name.... name='base'.